# How to confirm if insertInto is leveraging dynamic partition overwrite?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have the following reusable function that takes care of the initial load using `saveAsTable` and incremental updates using `insertInto`. `insertInto` also uses the *dynamic partition updates* feature by setting the option `partitionOverwriteMode` to `dynamic`. My question is if there is a way to check in Spark UI that this feature is being used.  I think the `number of dynamic part` from the following DAG indicates it, but I am not sure.

[image]

```
def saveAsManagedTable(df: DataFrame, dbOrSchemaName: String, tableName: String, partitionColNames: Array[String],
                         comment: String, numPartitions: Int = -1, saveMode: SaveMode = SaveMode.Overwrite,
                         fileFormat: StorageFormat = StorageFormat.Delta, otherWriterOpts: Map[String, String] = Map.empty): Unit = {
    //Check pre-conditions
    require((fileFormat.equals(StorageFormat.Delta) || fileFormat.equals(StorageFormat.Parquet)), "StorageFormat can be one of Delta or Parquet.")

    val spark = SynapseSpark.getActiveSession

    val fullTableName = s"$dbOrSchemaName.$tableName"
    println(
      s"""Saving as : $fullTableName, at location: ${spark.conf.get("spark.sql.warehouse.dir")},
         | with partition cols: ${partitionColNames.mkString(",")} and save mode: $saveMode""".stripMargin)
    
    if (!spark.catalog.databaseExists(dbOrSchemaName)) {
      spark.sql(
        s"""CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $dbOrSchemaName
           |COMMENT '$comment'
           |)
           |""".stripMargin)
    }
    val tempDf = Partitions.selectCoalesceOrRepartition(df, numPartitions)

    if (!spark.catalog.tableExists(fullTableName)) {
      println(s"$fullTableName doesn't exist in catalog. Creating it.")
      tempDf
        .write
        .partitionBy(partitionColNames: _*)
        .format(fileFormat.format)
        .options(otherWriterOpts)
        .option("encoding", StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())
        .mode(saveMode)
        .saveAsTable(fullTableName)
    }
    else {
      //Raises "AnalysisException: Table not found." if the table already doesn't exist
     println(s"$fullTableName already exists in catalog. Appending to it.")
      tempDf
        .write
        //.partitionBy(partitionCol) Not required as it retrieves the partition info from catalog
        .format(fileFormat.format)
        .options(otherWriterOpts)
        .option("partitionOverwriteMode", "dynamic") //The dynamic value makes sure that Spark will overwrite only partitions that we have data for in our DataFrame.
        .option("encoding", StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())
        .mode(saveMode) //mode is not needed as it is "Append" by default
        .insertInto(fullTableName)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily find if dynamic partition overwrite is enabled or not using the Environment tab in Spark UI:

[image]

Then search for the desired conf inside Spark Properties:

[image]

**UPDATE**

I'm affraid that you cannot use the conf inside write.options() if you want to see it in the spark ui, the options passed to .write.options() method are used by Spark to configure the write operation for a DataFrame or Dataset, but they do not affect the Spark runtime or environment like configuration settings.

The only solution is to set it using spark.conf.set("partitionOverwriteMode", "dynamic") before the write or add it to the spark-default.conf file if you want to use it everywhere

Comment: I am not seeing it under the Environment tab. May be because I am setting is as a option to the writer and not necessarily as a spark conf setting

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't answer my original question as I am using write.option